# how to send email and auto create appointment in receiver's outlook.

Tags: email, outlook, send, appointment

I have got a requirement, is there any way to send email to user, and when user  using their outlook to open it, auto create appointment in the receiver's outlook?

how to program that ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the example in the link below:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27451/Send-Calendar-Appointment-As-Email-Attachment